# error 404 on post request with ajax, php and json server

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, json-server

As said in the title, i get this error

> jquery.min.js:3049 POST http://localhost:3000/php/add_events.php 404 (Not Found)

when i try to access to a php file with that code on a json-server :

```
$.ajax({
    url: './php/add_events.php',
    data: 'title='+ eventData.title+'&start='+ eventData.start +'&end='+ eventData.end +'&areHere='+eventData.areHere+'&finalConsult='+eventData.finalConsult ,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
        alert("OK");
        eventData.id = json
    }
});
```

and when i try to set GET instead of POST, it works but it doesn't post (normal).
Here's the php code :

```
<?php

$title=$_POST['title'];
$start=$_POST['start'];
$end=$_POST['end'];
$areHere=$_POST['areHere'];
$finalConsult=$_POST['finalConsult'];
$typeConsult=$_POST['typeConsult'];
try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=agenda', 'root', '');
} catch(Exception $e) {
 exit('failed');
}

$sql = "sql insert into query";

$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':typeConsult'=>$typeConsult ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end, ':finalConsult'=>$finalConsult, ':areHere'=>$areHere));
$query = "some sql select query";
$result = $bdd->query($query) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Is the problem caused by me trying to post and get in the same php file ?
Or is it something else ?

Comment: your error says your url not found that's why you are getting error. Make sure your url is correct

Comment: @PankajMakwana i'm sure the url is correct because, as i said, with "get" instead of "post", it works (but doesn't do what i want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that POST aren't allowed on json-server, so i migrated on a apache server that's way better (for all that came here and want the solution)

Comment: You need to use PUT request to mutate the data with json-server

Answer (score 1):

Conver your data format like a json pattern:

```
data: { 'title': eventData.title, 'start' : eventData.start.......}
```

Right now yours is :

```
data: 'title='+ eventData.title+'&start='+ eventData.start +'&end='+ eventData.end +'&areHere='+eventData.areHere+'&finalConsult='+eventData.finalConsult
```

Comment: It seems to work but now i've an other error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined
    at D (moment.min.js:6)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2702)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:2695)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:2697)
    at Ab (jquery.min.js:2697)
    at Function.r.param (jquery.min.js:2709)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2934)
    at HTMLDivElement.click ((index):267)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.js:12443)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:1627)

Comment: This is other error. If you use a calendar plugin or other. Your first issue is solved please valid the good answer and create new issue post with more of your html.

Comment: Ok @P.Frank , I'm going to do that, if u can help me, please go on the new issue post i'll create

Comment: @P.Frank I found the solution

Comment: because i didn't make it, i can't for 90 minutes

Comment: but, after resolving this new error, it returns to the error of this issue post ... @P.Frank

Answer (score 1):

You post data without specify the `dataType`. Try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './php/add_events.php',
    data: 'title='+ eventData.title+'&start='+ eventData.start +'&end='+ eventData.end +'&areHere='+eventData.areHere+'&finalConsult='+eventData.finalConsult ,
    type: "POST",
    dataType : 'html', //Example
    success: function(json) {
        alert("OK");
        eventData.id = json
    }
});
```

or try if with post() you receive a result:

```
$.post( "./php/add_events.php", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data ok: " + data );
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! that's an other way, but I, as said by Hiamanshu, replaced the html-datas by json-datas and haven't anymore this error (it have been replaced by an other)

Answer (score 0):

I think for this request it need a absolute path, not a relative path.

I think you use routing by url like angularjs, if yes then you need to host php file in another server (independent by this url) and give absolute path.

For more accurate Answer please share full details of environments so can i help you out.

Comment: For the environment i'm working on json-server on port 3000 (localhost:3000), what do u want too ?

Comment: you use url for routing?

Comment: what do you mean by that ?